# Proper way of finding Articles that share a Tag in many-to-many relation on Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three tables, an articles table, a tags table, and an intermediate pivot table called article_tags, which only contains an article_id and tag_id, forming a many-to-many-relationship.

**I want to write a function that receives an Article, and returns a collection or query with all Articles that share at least one tag with the received Article**, after trying a bunch of different solutions, I have this:

```
public function scopeRelated($query, Article $article)
{
    return $query->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($article) {
        // I've tried a bunch of different lines, like just $article->tags
        $query->whereIn('tags', $article->tags->pluck('id'));
    });
}
```

This returns an error:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tags' in 'where clause' (SQL:
>   select * from `articles` where exists (select * from `tags` inner join
>   `article_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `article_tag`.`tag_id` where
>   `articles`.`id` = `article_tag`.`article_id` and `tags` in (1, 6,
>   4)))'

Evidently, Eloquent is trying to match the tags to a 'tags' column on the Articles table, which doesn't exist.
What would be the correct way of asking for what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tag_id` to be ultra-specific with the subquery:

```php
return $query->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($article) {
    $query->whereIn('tag_id', $article->tags->pluck('id'));
});
```

`'id'` as suggested in another answer worked for me in Laravel 5.8 and MySQL 5.7. Perhaps there's a certain strict mode enabled, or you actually DO have an `id` column in your `article_tag` table when you don't need it.

Also, don't forget to exclude the original article from the related results! :)

```php
$query
    ->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($article) {
        $query->whereIn('tag_id', $article->tags->pluck('id'));
    })
    ->where('id', '<>', $article->id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `'tags'` column with `'tags.id'`. Also if the `$article` object doesn't have tags relation already loaded, I would suggest `$article->tags()->pluck('id')` because this way eloquent will only query the article ids.

And [Aken Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/580587/aken-roberts) is right, you may want to exclude the `$article` from the results. I assume that the table with articles is called `articles`.

So the query would look like this:

```
    return $query->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($article) {
        $query->whereIn('tags.id', $article->tags()->pluck('id'));
    })->where('articles.id', '<>', $article->id);
```

Comment: This produces the error:
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `id` from `tags` inner join `article_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `article_tag`.`tag_id` where `article_tag`.`article_id` = 1)'

Comment: Right, it should be 'tags.id' so that mysql knows which table does the id refer to. Edited my answer.