# Laravel whereIn query says column doesn't exist on Many to Many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table, relationship

I have a Many to Many relationship between two Models `Content` and `Tag`, with a pivot table

```
// content_tag Pivot Table
=======================
| content_id | tag_id |
=======================
```

```
// Models\Content
 
public function tags()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

```
// Models\Tag
 
public function content()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Content::class);
}
```

In my controller I am trying to user `whereIn` to return a subset of `Content`, filtered by tag:

```
// Content Controller

...

$tags = [1, 2]
Content::whereIn('tags', $tags)->get();
```

This returns an error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tags' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `contents` where `tags` in (2))
```

I've tried specifying the pivot table columns in the Models as that seemed to help another SO user with a somewhat similar issue:

```
// Models\Content

public function tags()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'content_tag', 'content_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

That didn't make any difference - same error.

I can do this with a `whereHas` query, and [a related SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485279/proper-way-of-finding-articles-that-share-a-tag-in-many-to-many-relation-on-lara) suggests that, but apparently 'whereHas' has poor performance and whereIn would be a better to deal with this?

```
// Content Controller - this works!

Cotnent::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tags) {
  foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $query->where('tags.id', $tag);
  }
});
```

Is there a way to do this with whereIn, or what is the most elegant way to tackle this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `Content` model's database table `contents` doesn't have a `tags` column, and you're not doing any kind of `join()`, so the error is correct. You either have to use `whereHas()` to perform a subquery to search against it, or `Content::join('tags', ...)->whereIn('tags.id', $tags);`, etc.

Comment: Also, `foreach ($tags as $tag) { $query->where('tags.id', $tag); }` is nonsensical... Just do `$query->whereIn('tags.id', $tags);`

Comment: `whereIn()` is a query builder method that works with the database. `whereHas()` is an Eloquent method that works with relationships. Two very different things. You are almost certainly not going to be affected by "poor performance" when working with relationship queries. My app handles >100k requests a day on a $25/month DigitalOcean droplet without any performance issues. 95% of my queries are using Eloquent.

Comment: Thanks both; I consider both of these acceptable answers to the question, so if either of you want to submit as an answer, I will accept.